# LaTeX filepaths in Ubuntu

Tags: directory, latex, rm

I'm sorry, this is quite a specific and esoteric question, but I thought if anyone could help...

Well, anyway, last night I used `ls` to look at a directory and noticed some junk hidden files I didn't want. So, unthinkingly, I ran `rm ./.*` to clear them. Unfortunately, I was still in `~`. Well, you can imagine.

Happily this has had very few adverse effects, as it obviously didn't delete any directories, but it seems to have deleted a LaTeX config file or something.

I really have no idea what I've accidentally gotten rid of, but I had to reinstall texlive, just to be able to run `pdflatex` and `xelatex` and whilst they do now work, it's having trouble finding packages, which are definitely present in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`

If I move the appropriate `.sty` files from here, then I have no problems. But, as you can imagine, apart from the fact that this isn't a very satisfactory solution, I also make extensive use of the latest versions of the `fontspec` package, which, sadly, is dependent on a lot of other packages and files that don't seem to come with `apt-get`'s verion of texlive.

So, my question to you is: do you know of the hidden file which I might have deleted (and which I need to put back) that could be causing this? Or, at least, is there a simpler fix than 'rejigging' the entire file system?

Comment: I have TexLive installed and I have no obvious TeXLive hidden files directly under my home directory. The only thing I can think of might be .profile or .bashrc.

Comment: Thanks for having a look for me :) At the moment I seem to have, one way or another, got things working again. However, the `covington` package, has had to be copied into `~/texmf/tex/latex/` so that it can be found and there are a few packages behaving differently. For example, I no longer have access to `\textsubscript{}` without manually loading `fixltx2e` which I didn't have to do before and I have to load `color` as well, which - in some files, I didn't have to do. I think, in short, that one of my packages must have loaded these for me, so - presumably - there's been a version reversion.

Answer (score 9):

The only occasion that TeXlive has been installed in `/usr/local/texlive` is when I have done
a **manual** install. That is, I've gone to `www.tug.org`, downloaded the Linux binary, etc.

If I use `apt-get install texlive` (or Ubuntu Software Center), TeXlive ends up in `/usr/share` by default.

So if you didn't do anything different from this two options, I guess that the problem
is:

1. You did a manual install (via `www.tug.org`). For this to work, the installer created
   hidden files in your home directory, which you accidentally erased.
2. Then you installed TeXlive via `apt-get` or Ubuntu Software Center. Notice that
   (unless you've installed the `texlive-full` package) you won't have installed all
   the packages you might need.

So even if you have the packages you need installed in `/usr/local/texlive`, the installation
via `apt-get` only can see the packages installed in `/usr/share`.

My recommendation is to install `texlive-full` or even better:

`sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-latex-extra cm-super`

if you don't need "everything").
After that you might consider uninstalling the TeXlive installed manually in
`/usr/local/texlive` (I'm not sure right now if you can directly `sudo rm -R /usr/local/texlive`
or if there is an uninstaller included somewhere in `/usr/local/texlive`).

Comment: I think that's a very good call. I've done that, and I think I now have two texlive installations, which is a little bit inelegant, but no matter. Everything I need right now seems to be working. I suppose, in time, I might found out that some functionality's gone missing, but I can reinstall packages when I find out I've lost them. Although, the texlive install in `/usr/share` is a lot lighter and it seems odd having LaTeX files all over the place, especially as I have a `~/texmf/` directory too. Is there no way to just get it to go back to using the files in `/usr/local/texlive`?

Comment: You might want to try and get the files you erased from www.tug.org, I guess. I mean they must have been 'quite default' files so if you google for them you might find them. Then just copy these files to your home folder and it might work. Also TeXlive (in `/usr/local`) should have some tool to recreate these files you could try googling about that too.

Comment: Packages location are in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty`